# Get define/const value from header to shell?

Tags: c, shell

Suppose one has some header, the if normally writing some C program one would include with `-I/path/header.h`. It has bunch of `#defines` some of them being "compound" like `#define SOMECONST SOME_PREPROC_FUNC(3)` and also some enums.

What could be the good way to get the value of `SOME_CONST` and `SOME_ENUM` to shell in hopefully one line? Without writing compiling custom executable. Pseudo thingie that would not work, but hopefully illustrates this:

```
./$(cc '#include <header>\n#include <stdio>\nvoid main () {printf("%d\n", $const_or_enum_name);}' -I/path/header.h)
```

Or maybe using some other tool?

Comment: Yes, the value of constant/enum returned as say output of a command.

Comment: Your pseudo thingie might not be the best way but it's not that bad of an idea either. Did you try it? You can pipe source into gcc and you'd have to run the executable after compilation but it should work.

Comment: You are not free to use `void main` in a hosted implementation; it must be `int main`.

Comment: "one would include with `-I/path/header.h`" - normally not. `#include`ing headers **in** the code is the recommended way.

Comment: just pointing out that you are being overly and irrelevantly pedanting @Jens and Olaf, this is you'r points are known (except that you need -I in any case if .h is not in current dir) and are irrelevant to question being asked.

Comment: @morphles You should value pedantry. It improves your and other readers future code when you are shown where you violated the C Standard. That's a good thing. We've all been taught by the experts and learnt our craft from being pointed to places where we could have done better.

Answer (score 2):

You can perform preprocessor step and stop after that. This can be done using `cc -E`.

```
$ cat header.h
#define VAR 3
$ echo -e "#include \"header.h\"\nVAR" | cc -E -xc -
<lots of stuff>
3
$ echo -e "#include \"header.h\"\nVAR" | cc -E -xc - | tail -1
3
```

This actually tells `cc` to run preprocessor on `stdin`, printing result to `stdout`. `-xc` is needed to specify that the language is actually C.

Slightly more advanced example:

```
$ cat header.h 
#define VAR1 3
#define VAR2 5
#define VAR3 VAR1*VAR2
$ echo -e "#include \"header.h\"\nVAR3" | cc -E -xc - | tail -1 | bc
15
```

Comment: Multiline defines would be joined as single line - just tested that. On the other hand this won't do any calculations, so if `VAR` is for example `VAL*OTHER_VAL` result would be something like `3 * 5`

Comment: Yes that calculation issue is a bit of a bummer, possibly one can fore it somehow. Will have to look up.

Comment: Seems using m4 preprocessor should allow one to achieve this, but will have to look at it more.

Comment: So for my case (which was a bit more complicated) bc did not work, but doing `..\neval(VAR3)" cc -E -xc - | tail -1 | m4` works. Still all of this leaves enums... As preprocessor can't return/know enum value.